# How to manually generate a node's SignedNodeInfo file

Tags: corda

I am using an Azure VMs to run my nodes on Corda V3. How do I manually generate the `nodeInfo-...` file for each node so I can distribute across the network (without using the network-bootstrapper.

There's some documentation about using `--just-generate-node-info` [here](https://docs.corda.net/head/network-map.html#the-additional-node-infos-directory) but I'm not sure how do I run this in the command line on the node?

Answer (score 1):

Go to the node folder and run the following:

```
java -jar corda.jar --just-generate-node-info
```

This will create the node-info file in the same folder, with the name `nodeInfo-<IDENTIFIER>`.